# updating element with new value from ajax call failing

Tags: jquery, ajax, json

I think I have a syntax problem somewhere.
I successfully make an ajax call and get the new value I want to use as a value for a button.
I can see the correct data in the console, but the value of the button never changes. 
Here's the code:

```
$('.changestatus').live('click', function()  {
    var id = this.id;
    console.log(this.id);
    var parameters = {
        rule_id: this.id,
        rule_status: this.value,
        viewtype:'json'
    };

    var url = myurl;
    console.log(myurl);
    $.getJSON(
        url,
        parameters,
        function(data) {
            console.log(data);   
            $(id).value = data; //this.value = data;
        }
    );//end getJSON.    
});//end click.
```

Can you tell me where I'm going wrong?  within the context of the json call, is it still aware of "this" - being the button that was clicked?

thanks.

Comment: `.live()` is deprecated, what jQuery version do you have?

Comment: 1.5.2 is the version i'm running

Comment: did you mean `$('.changestatus').value= data;` ?

Comment: @andrew probably not what if there are multiple `.changestatus` elements

Comment: andrew, no because I will have multiple buttons with the same class, different ids.

Comment: oh yes i see what hes doing so it should be `$('#'+id)`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should use `val()` instead of `value` on jquery object.

```
$('#' + id).val(data);
```

or

```
document.getElementById(id).value=data;
```

You can also do this way, by caching the `this` context to a variable `self` and set the value with `self.value=data` inside the success callback.

```
$('.changestatus').live('click', function()  {
    var id = this.id;
    var self = this; //<-- Here
    console.log(this.id);
    .....

    $.getJSON(
        url,
        parameters,
        function(data) {
            ...  
            self.value = data; 
            ...
        }
    );//end getJSON.    
});//end click.
```

> As of jQuery 1.7, the .live() method is deprecated. Use .on() to attach event handlers. Users of older versions of jQuery should use .delegate() in preference to .live().

Comment: The first example would need to be `$('#' + id).val(data);`

Comment: that's great!  it works.  thanks so much.  and as soon as we upgrade to 1.7 i will change to use ON

Answer (score 0):

Assuming everything else is correct, you should be getting the id like this:

```
var id = $(this).attr('id');
```

From there, you need to:

```
$('#' + id).val(data);
```

jQuery selectors use a hash to denote that it is an ID, since it is a general purpose selector.

Comment: `var id = this.id;` is ok also.

Comment: FYI `this.id` is perfectly valid, and is much faster than creating a jQuery object just to get a native attribute from a DOM element.